# Como obter relatórios do banco através de aplicação web?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, aplicação-web

Onde trabalho existem alguns procedimentos no banco de dados (SQL Server 2008) que levam horas pra serem executados e retornam grandes quantidades de informação que são sempre copiadas pra uma planilha e enviada pro usuário final.

Até existem algumas aplicações desktop que podem executá-los mas isso não é muito prático;

*Exemplo processado:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma de automatizar esses relatórios através de uma aplicação web?

Seria perfeito se houvesse alguma forma do usuário disparar o procedimento e deixá-lo executando através da web para que em outro momento ele pudesse entrar novamente no site e pegar o relatório.

Conheço um pouco de asp.net, mas não tenho ideia se dá fazer isso...

Atualmente os relatórios são deixados sendo executados na máquina do usuário através de uma aplicação desktop que gera um arquivo do Excel ou através do próprio SQL Server Management Studio onde quem estiver dando o suporte se conecta ao banco de dados...

*Deixa o procedimento executando no servidor*
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando ele termina de executar, copia o resultado pra uma planilha do Excel e envia pro usuário que solicitou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas vários desses procedimentos são demorados e por isso gostaria que tivesse uma forma de deixar o usuário fazer isso por uma aplicação web.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Respondendo, existe.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Que tipo de aplicação web pode suportar 1 hora de execução do procedimento sem dar timeout?

Comment: 1h de execução de procedimento é um absurdo. Qual o motivo de ser tão extenso?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Não sei porque é tão demorado. Mas esse ainda nem é o mais lento. Existem outros que demoram mais...

Comment: O que a aplicação web pode fazer é disparar um outro procedimento remoto que produza essa massa de dados, mas não que ela vá esperar o fim dessa execução.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Seria perfeito se houvesse alguma forma de disparar o procedimento e deixá-lo executando para que em outro momento o usuário pudesse entrar pegar o relatório.

Comment: Bom, então edite sua pergunta e coloque exatamente isso. Procure também especificar qual plataforma gostaria que isso fosse desenvolvido. Se você não tem ideia de plataforma, deixe isso claro na sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez acabo de alterar

Comment: Isto já melhora algumas coisas. Agora preciso que você edite novamente sua pergunta e explique pra gente como esses procedimentos são ativados hoje. Essa parte é essencial pra que eu possa escrever uma resposta razoável.

Comment: Ok @CiganoMorrisonMendez acabo de alterar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pra essa resposta eu vou ter que dar linhas gerais, pois o detalhamento da implementação ficaria muito extenso.

O que temos na sua pergunta é uma *Stored Procedure* em Microsoft SQL Server que é chamada, processa informações e devolve como retorno uma tabela que é convertida em planilha. Antes mesmo de escrever uma aplicação Web para lidar com isso, é possível antes promover algumas modificações a nível de *Stored Procedure* que poderão ajudar muito no seu trabalho.

## 1. Crie uma tabela de requisições de relatórios

Não sei como é o formato dos dados de vocês, mas penso em alguma coisa assim:

```
CREATE TABLE REQUISICAO_RELATORIO
(
    REQUISICAO_RELATORIO_ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    USUARIO_ID INT, -- Eu estou chutando que o usuário tenha isso, só para exemplo.
    DATA_REQUISICAO DATETIME DEFAULT getdate(),
    STATUS VARCHAR(100), -- Pode ser 'Iniciado', 'Concluido', 'Falha',
    TIPO_RELATORIO VARCHAR(100) -- Aparentemente tem tipos de relatórios. Use esse campo para preencher.
)
```

Cada pedido de relatório vai inserir uma linha nessa tabela. A *Stored Procedure* vai processar os dados normalmente e, ao terminar a tarefa, vai atualizar os dados dessa tabela.

## 2. Insira os dados de retorno numa tabela referenciada por `REQUISICAO_RELATORIO`

Faça uma nova tabela, inserindo uma coluna de chave estrangeira que faz referência a `REQUISICAO_RELATORIO`. Essa nova tabela vai ter exatamente os mesmos dados de retorno que vão na sua planilha de Excel.

Para selecionar os dados, você pode, inclusive, selecionar todos os dados a qualquer momento, mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA_COM_DADOS_DO_EXCEL
WHERE REQUISICAO_RELATORIO_ID = 1
```

Ou então usando outros campos. O importante é preservar os dados para serem selecionados a qualquer momento.

## 3. Crie tarefas que leiam `REQUISICAO_RELATORIO` e executem a *Stored Procedure*

[Para aprender a criar tarefas no SQL Server, veja este link](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/257/sql-server/criando-e-executando-jobs-no-sql-server/).

Assim você consegue agendar processamentos e não precisa ficar com uma janela do Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Note que depois desses 3 passos, a implementação de uma aplicação Web se torna totalmente opcional.